# How to recover Mediarecorder object reference created and started within an IntentService

Tags: android, intentservice, mediarecorder

I know I should rather use a Service but I just would like to know if one can solve this kind of issue within an intent Service.

I have a mediarecorder (audio) which is initiated and started within an intentservice. Then the intentservice stop by itself as onHandleIntent() fisnished and there is nothing more in the queu,e but the mediarecorder continue to record in the background (I see the size of the recording file continue  increasing) I guess it has its own thread.

Now I want to create an intent (could be trigger by Alarm Manager) that will stop the Mediarecorder, but when the intent reach the intentservice the reference to the mediarecorder is lost as the intentservice has been previously stopped

Is there a way to solve this (beside object Serialization) ?

Comment: "Is there a way to solve this" -- do not use an `IntentService`. `IntentService` does not work all that well on Android 8.0+ anyway. "beside object Serialization" -- object serialization will not help here. You need to step back and ask yourself why you are using any type of service. If the answer is "to keep the recorder running while the app's UI is in the background", then an `IntentService` is pointless, because the service goes away right away. You would need to use a regular foreground `Service` just for your functionality objective, let alone for dealing with the `MediaRecorder` object.

Comment: I agree (I first said that I should use a service) but I was surprised that the MediaRecorder was not killed when then onHandleIntent return and The Intent Service Stop. So I was wondering if there was a way to keep a reference to the object (probably I'm one of these C++ people who cannot survive without pointer :-) )

Comment: "So I was wondering if there was a way to keep a reference to the object" -- it would have to be something outside of the `IntentService` instance. That could be a `static` field or some sort of singleton. You risk a memory leak, though.

Comment: Yes singleton, and after reading some about it I understand why one has to be careful with it, Thanks for your help

Comment: @CommonsWare Side note : It would be a different story with another type of Recorder, but as MediaRecorder works in the background by itself and the service is used only for action like starting and stopping the recorder, it does not seem such a mistake to use an IntentService to handle that. I made an experiment with a static variable pointing to the MediaRecorder and an AlarmManager to stop and restart the recorder every 15mn with a new output file. I let it run 10 hours and it worked perfectly

Comment: "I let it run 10 hours and it worked perfectly" -- without a running service, your process can be terminated within milliseconds of entering the background. Even *with* a running service, your process can be terminated, particularly on Android 8.0+.

Comment: I know and that's the reason I was surprised by the result and  was wondering whether MediaRecorder could be itself running inside a service immune to termination by the OS